# How Do I Handle Forward References with IF Pseudo Ops in an assembler

Tags: python, python-3.x, assembly, 6502

I am writing a 6502 assembler in Python, and have no idea how to handle this:

It's a two pass assembler, so it figures out symbols in the first pass, then fills them in in the second. Standard stuff. But! I want it to have an ".if" pseudo op, where it will conditionally execute code based on a condition.

So what do I do if the .if pseudo op is testing a forward referenced symbol that has not yet been defined in the first pass?? Without it, I can't expand the code properly to figure out the location of labels to determine symbols!

I was thinking maybe I could simulatenously generate multiple versions of the symbol table based on whether or not the if statement finds Truth, then deciding which version to use in the second pass, but that sounds like a *terrible* hit to my performance.

Comment: What do you mean "testing a symbol"?  Is this purely an assemble-time condition, like NASM `%if` or C preprocessor `#ifdef` (but allowing forward refs)?  Or do you mean  a MASM-style (.if / .else / .while) thing that assembles into a runtime test of the byte stored at a symbol?

Comment: You might find it interesting to read NASM's documentation for its "critical expressions": https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.8.  A critical expression must be resolvable on the first pass.  (NASM is open source, so if you're curious about how they implement their multiple optimization passes for x86 short vs. near branch displacements and so on, have a look.)

Comment: It's an assembly-level check, but yeah, according to this NASM stuff, it can't be forward referenced

Comment: Is that an acceptable restriction for your assembler?  To simply disallow forward refs for your `.if` directives?  Note that NASM's `%ifdef` checks *macro* definitions from `%define foo 1`, not *symbol* definitions like `foo:`.   So a later definition isn't an error, it just wasn't defined at the time.  (And BTW, terminology: "pseudo-op" implies emitting bytes into the output file, like how MIPS `li` can assemble to `lui` / `ori` for a large 32-bit constant, or `db` assembles arbitrary bytes into the output , while "directive" implies changing assembler settings / options, or stuff like this.)

Comment: I want if statements to conditionally assemble code based on a condition check via expressions that can include labels, for instance ".if label1-label2 > $ff", but I'm not sure if I can do that with a forward label reference, because the value of forward labels depends of whether or not the code after the if gets assembled or not

Comment: Ok, I see.  NASM doesn't support that, because as you've discovered there's no efficient way to implement it.  In the general case, you could get an infinite loop where re-assembling after deciding that a `.if` is true makes it false again, and vice versa.  Or with multiple `.if` directives nested or otherwise interacting, it could be very computationally intensive to solve.  (A bit like C++ templates that can create an arbitrary amount of compile-time computation, but this wouldn't usually be as useful or powerful.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to your question, more an explanation of why you can admit defeat with honour intact.

Consider the following:

```
.org $400
label1: nop
.if label2 - label1 == 1
        nop
.endif
label2: nop
```

What's the final assembly? If the bit inside the `.if` is *excluded* than the condition is true and the bit inside the `.if` should be *included*. Conversely, if the bit inside the `.if` is *included* the condition is false and the `.if` should be excluded.

I think it's perfectly reasonable to restrict the `.if` from using labels that are defined further down the code.